# Is "Do you afraid of..." correct?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage, usage

I recently saw the phrase "Do you afraid of pain?" in an official translation. Is this just a translation mistake or grammatically correct?

Comment: Which official translation of what? It might be a mistake or it might be the author making one of the characters speak bad English. But without context we can only guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a mistake.

The correct wording would be, "Are you afraid of pain?" "Afraid" is an adjective. You cannot "do" an adjective, you can only "do" a verb. You can "be" an adjective.

If for some reason you wanted to use the word "do", you'd have to reword the sentence to use a verb instead of the adjective "afraid". Like, "Do you fear pain?"